# magento 2 Rest api cart merge guest cart and already customer active cart

Tags: api, magento, magento2

```
As Alex Gusev cleared in their [reply][1]  Magento 2 REST can not distinguish between authenticated and anonymous customers. Web services ACL is applied for admin users only. All customers are anonymous for REST services.
But there is a method in magento 2 for rest api swagger http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ Here we can assign guest cart to customer using quoteGuestCartManagementV1 using method. 
But The only problem is that if customer already have active cart (item in cart). then it throw exception.
```

Cannot assign customer to the given cart. Customer already has active cart. otherwise its working fine.
    Is there any solution for merging guest quote/cart to customer cart/quote. if customer already have active cart?

Comment: I think this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/how-to-copy-one-quote-only-cart-items-to-other-quote-only-items/30460#30460) will help you

Comment: no I am asking about magento 2 not 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create "Around" Plugin in your custom extension.

**app/code/MageKnight/Quote/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MageKnight_Quote">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>            
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/MageKnight/Quote/registration.php**

```
<?php

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'MageKnight_Quote', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/MageKnight/Quote/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="mergeGuestCart"
                type="MageKnight\Quote\Plugin\Model\CartManagement"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/MageKnight/Quote/Plugin/Model/CartManagement.php**

```
<?php

namespace MageKnight\Quote\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;

/**
 * Class CartManagement
 */
class CartManagement
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerModelFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory
     */
    private $quoteIdMaskFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModelFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerModelFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->customerModelFactory = $customerModelFactory;
        $this->quoteIdMaskFactory = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Around plugin to assign customer to guest cart
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param int $cartId The cart ID.
     * @param int $customerId The customer ID.
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function aroundAssignCustomer(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        $cartId,
        $customerId,
        $storeId
    ) {
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $customerModel = $this->customerModelFactory->create();

        if (!in_array($storeId, $customerModel->load($customerId)->getSharedStoreIds())) {
            throw new StateException(
                __("The customer can't be assigned to the cart. The cart belongs to a different store.")
            );
        }
        if ($quote->getCustomerId()) {
            throw new StateException(
                __("The customer can't be assigned to the cart because the cart isn't anonymous.")
            );
        }
        try {
            $customerActiveQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($customerId);
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $customerActiveQuote = false;
        }
        if ($customerActiveQuote) {
            /** Merge carts */
            $quote->merge($customerActiveQuote);
            $this->quoteRepository->delete($customerActiveQuote);
        }
        $quote->setCustomer($customer);
        $quote->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
        $quote->setStoreId($storeId);
        $quote->setIsActive(1);
        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMask $quoteIdMask */
        $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'quote_id');
        if ($quoteIdMask->getId()) {
            $quoteIdMask->delete();
        }
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing with problem **The customer can't be assigned to the cart because the cart isn't anonymous.**. I don't know what problem with that cart. can anyone help me?